# toCharArray() with 2 dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Who can i use this function inside a bucle storing the characters in a 2D array?

```
char[] characters = string.toCharArray();
```

My approach was the following:

```
String [] string ={"abc" , "def", "ghi"};
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  char[i][] characters = string[i].toCharArray();
```

EDIT: the result should be something like this:
character[0][0]='a'; character[0][1]='b'; character[1][0]='d'; ...

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: According to eclipse: cannot convert from char[] to char (being string[i].toCharArray() red underlined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to define the char array outside the for loop.

```
String [] string ={"abc" , "def", "ghi"};
char characters[][] = new char[string.length][];//make this 2d
for (int i=0; i<characters.length; i++)
    characters[i] = string[i].toCharArray();
```

Cheers.

Comment: new char[string.length] might be problematic

Comment: use new char[string.length][]; instead

Comment: @Builder_K you are correct I forgot the brackets. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] strings ={"abc" , "def", "ghi"};
char characters[][] = new char[string.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        characters[i][j] = strings[i].toCharArray()[j];
    }
}
```

So what are we doing here actually elementary thing.

1. `strings[i].toCharArray()` is returning an array of characters. `strings[0].toCharArray()` = `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` and so on.
2. Now `strings[i].toCharArray()[j]` will pick one by one character and place it in the 2-D array(matrix) `characters`.